# Exchange Email Notification doesn't clear

Tags: email, notifications, outlook

I have a couple Google Mail (apps and gmail) accounts linked to my phone. If I get email the phone notifies me. If I read the email on a PC, the notification goes away. I like that.

I also am using the "Email" app with an Exchange server for my day job. If I get email the phone notifies me. However, if I read the email on PC (outlook or outlook web access) the notification never clears. So, I see the notification on the phone, tap through and... find nothing new.

Is there a setting that I'm missing?

[edit] running 2.1, if that matters.

[edit] Feb 1, 2011. This is still an issue since the Android 2.2 update as well

Comment: I should ask: Has anyone else seen this behavior from the non-gmail email app?

Comment: Yes, I see the same thing with the built-in e-mail app.

Comment: Don't use the built-in Email app anymore, but I definitely used to see that when I had it connected to a POP account, the notification never went away until I opened the Email app, even if I'd already read the mail via that account's web interface.

Comment: You could always use the "Clear" button when you pull down the notification area. That'll get rid of the notification without forcing you to go into the app.

Comment: Al E -- that works if I'm sitting at my desk exclusively managing email in Outlook. Which rarely happens. Instead, I find myself looking at that new mail indicator on the phone wondering if that came in since my last look at Outlook or not. Did I remember to clear the phone then? Or was I busy and working and missed a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away after the ICS update was pushed out.

Answer (score 1):

How often is your Exchange email on your phone syncing to the Exchange server? It may not be going away because the sync isn't set soon enough?  My guess is that it doesn't know that the email was marked as read until it syncs back to the server.

Comment: The Account Settings assure me it is in Push mode.

Comment: As a side note: I've experimented with  push and various interval times. No diffs.

Answer (score 1):

The issue persisted even after the 2.2 upgrade.

Switching to Touchdown is one reasonably inexpensive alternative.

Comment: While I haven't made the switch to Touchdown yet, a coworker has been using it for a while and is very happy with it.

Comment: I did the 30 day trial. Liked it quite a bit but haven't yet pulled the trigger on buying.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using K-9 Mail, a much better email app than the built-in. On my IMAP4 accounts, the notifications are cleared when the phone pulls the emails again. Haven't tried this with a push account, but i'd imagine it will work with a possible delay of your pull interval.

Comment: K-9 looks interesting, but the "quirky" warning about working with Exchange servers makes me rather nervous. My initial attempts to use it haven't gone well, I'm afraid (we don't have IMAP4 enabled).

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that, forgot that I didn't test Exchange on K9.